# First record in table overlapped by header of table in IE

Tags: css, grails, gsp

Created a table which works fine in IE6,7 but in FF the header hides the first datarow.

```
<g:if test="${params.history!=null}">
<div style="width:791px;padding-bottom:10px;overflow-y:auto;${(lstDNCallEntries.size()>0)?'height:100px':''}">
<table class="table">
<thead style="position: absolute;">
 <% params=params.findAll{ k,v -> k != 'sort'} %>
<td class="certify_head" width="87" style="text-align: center">title</td>
<td class="certify_head" width="89" style="text-align: center" >action</td>
            <td class="certify_head" width="66" style="text-align: center" >list</td>
            <td class="certify_head" width="118" style="text-align: center" >selection</td>
            <td class="certify_head" width="110" style="text-align: center" >source</td>
            <td class="certify_head" width="64" style="text-align: center" >${message(code:'phoneoptoutgranularity.gsp~title.user')}</td>
            <td class="certify_head" width="82" style="text-align: center" >Office</td>
            <td class="certify_head" width="90" style="text-align: center" >Effective Date</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="scrollContent">
            <g:if test="${lstDNCallEntries.size() > 0}">
                <g:each in="${lstDNCallEntries}" var="phoneHistory" status="i">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'normalRow' : 'alternateRow'}"
                            onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffd9'"
                            onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
                        <td width="90" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.date}</td>
                        <td width="92" valign="center" style="font: normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">${phoneHistory.action}</td>
                        <td width="71" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.list}</td>
                        <td width="122" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.preferencekey}</td>
                        <td width="110" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.source}</td>
                        <td width="69" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.user}</td>
                        <td width="85" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.office}</td>
                        <td width="90" align="center" valign="center">${phoneHistory.effectiveDate}</td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <tr>
                    <b>
                    <td colspan="7" width="770" align="center"><b><g:message
                        code="phoneoptoutgranularity.gsp~historydetails" /></b></td>
                    </b>
                </tr>
            </g:else>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</g:if>
```

Please help where i can modify.

-ss

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `<tr>` in your top row.

Answer (score 0):

Why is that `position:absolute` in there? Off the top of my head, pos:abs will take the `thead` out of the flow which will bump the first row up effectively hiding it. Possibly you could fix this with some margin/padding on the first row but you'd have to justify the pos:abs first.

The other thing I can see is that all the `thead` contents are `td`'s not `th`'s, but I doubt that would create this effect.

edit: gave it a rough test, it's definitely the pos:abs (root of all evil :P). Possibly you want `position:fixed` instead? And the other poster is right, you're missing a `tr`